# Intellij 14 Project window stealing focus from code window

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-14

Since upgrading to Intellij 14 I'm having this strange issue where focus gets permanently stolen by the Project tree structure window so that I cannot Code.  When I try typing or high-lighting nothing works...neither by keyboard nor mouse.  When I type letters it starts searching through the project hierarchy.

Is anyone else experiencing this extremely obnoxious behavior and does anyone know how I can avoid having it happen.  The only work-around I've found is to close intellij and re-launch.  There seems to be no other way to get focus back to the coding window.

Tagging this question Java since our app is written in Java and I'm just trying to edit classes.

Comment: Have you tried hitting escape? That has always restored focus into the editor.

Comment: Yes, tried escape many many times.  Tried all sorts of things.  Stack overflow was my last hope.

Comment: This might be environmental.  What OS and version of Java are you running?

Comment: Windows 8.1 64 bit, Java 1.7.0_79 also 64 bit

Comment: @UncleIroh Did you find a solution? I'm having the [same problem here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31698041/543711) but with Android Studio.

Comment: @iturki Unfortunately I have yet to have found a solution.  Though it has been happening less.  For me it seems to have something to do with multiple instances of Intellij running.  Lately I have been mostly running a single instance (haven't had to open the other projects) and so it's been pretty normal. (Are you also running multiple instances of intellij?)

Comment: @UncleIroh No. Only the one instance. However, I stumbled upon a trick (by accident :) ) that will give the focus back to the Code view. When you lose focus, click on the far right of the view; the small part where the scrollbar appears. This should give the focus back, at least it is the case in Android Studio.

Comment: @iturki It happened to me again just barely and this was the only instance of intellij I was running (however I did have two instances open earlier today).  Your trick of clicking where the scrollbar is DID give the code view the focus back!!!  So thanks!  However it's only temporary and as soon as I switch to a different class or press cntrl+f to find something etc the focus is lost again and I have to do you trick on the scroll bar to get it back again....So still frustrated, but your trick works to some degree.